# Swift fails on iOS 10, on 9 and lower works fine

Tags: swift, ios10

This part of code is not working (if-part). Service.Start calls JSONSerializer and parses json.

```
Service.Start(nil, url: someUrl, onCompletion: { result in
    if let temp = result as? NSMutableDictionary {
        //some code
    }
```

Code for getting result:

```
let parsedObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary
                    onCompletion(parsedObject)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working". Is it crashing? Is it not compiling? Is it not entering the if block? Also, why are you using `NSMutableDictionary`? You should NEVER use that in Swift... ever.

Comment: Also, please make sure to enter all your relevant code in the question. The code as it is does not make sense or compile with any version of Swift.

Comment: if-condition fails (doesn't execute code inside, but only on ios 10). result is json

Comment: Ok I just realized this:
result in iOS10 has type __NSDictionaryI,
result in iOS8 has type  __NSCFDictionary

Comment: Did you use options `[.mutableContainers]` when parsing the JSON? If not, you cannot get a mutable dictionary.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you. It worked. Can you explain this please? Or can you give me some reference to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use options `[.mutableContainers]` the parser won't use mutable dictionaries and mutable arrays when parsing.

Therefore the cast to `NSMutableDictionary` won't succeed. You will have just the immutable `NSDictionary`.

However, using either is not a good solution in Swift code.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is new in iOS 10

Comment: @Faruk It's not new. Previously it was passing for you only by pure luck. The way Swift imported `__NSCFDictionary` could hide the immutability because Swift doesn't distinguish mutable and immutable types, only mutable and immutable variables.